# C++ String Interview Question

Tags: c++, optimization, string, processing-efficiency

I was recently in a C++ technical interview, where I was given a bit of simple string manipulation code, which is intended to take a string and return a string that is comprised of the first and last n-characters, and then proceed to correct any bugs and to also make the function as efficient as possible, I came up with the solution below, however the interviewer claimed there was an even faster more optimal way:

Original code:

```
std::string first_last_n(int n, std::string s)
{
   std::string first_n = s.substr(0,n);
   std::string last_n = s.substr(s.size()-n-1,n);
   return first_n + last_n;
}
```

My code:

```
bool first_last_n(const std::size_t& n, const std::string& s, std::string& r)
{
   if (s.size() < n)
      return false;
   r.reserve(2 * n);
   r.resize(0);
   r.append(s.data(),s.data() + n);
   r.append(s.data() + (s.size() - n), s.data() + s.size());
   return true;
}
```

Summary of my changes:

- Changed the interface to take a return string as reference (assuming RVO and rvalues are not available yet)
- Removed temporary strings being constructed via substr
- Passed input string as a const reference inorder to get around temporary instantiation of input
- Fixed off-by-1 error in last_n string
- Reduced the number of times each character is touched down to once, or twice (in the event of an overlapping scenario)
- Placed a check in the event the string s's size is less than n, returning false for failure.

Assuming only native C++ is allowed, is there some other way of doing the above more efficiently or optimally?

**Note 1:** The original input string instance is not to be modified.

**Note 2:** All solutions must pass the following test case, otherwise they are not valid.

```
void test()
{
   {
      std::string s = "0123456789";
      std::string r = first_last_n(10,s);
      assert(r == "01234567890123456789");
   }

   {
      std::string s = "0123456789ABC0123456789";
      std::string r = first_last_n(10,s);
      assert(r == "01234567890123456789");
   }

   {
      std::string s = "1234321";
      std::string r = first_last_n(5,s);
      assert(r == "1234334321");
   }

}
```

Comment: You can only guess (or physically measure) at which one is optimal as they will both be affected by the actual underlying implementation of std::string. Personally I prefer the first one as it is intuitively easy to read. But if this was designed for reuse in a library (like the STL) I would go for the second one (iff I could prove there was some real advantage). The advantage of the second was is the use of reserve to make sure there is not too much copying involved. *Also note*: copying back a string is not as expensive as you imagine as most implementations use copy on write.

Comment: That is not entirely true, as there are some guarantees about how memory is stored and accessed given certain routines. Even assuming MS style small-strings there's still some assumptions that can be made.

Comment: Did you have to return a `string` object? There is the option of returning an object which contains pointers to chunks of the two substrings in the original string, which would be O(1) but very dependent on how you use the result.

Comment: @marcog: the original usage is something like: std::string result =  first_last_n(17,s);

Comment: The best one so far was @Charles Bailey. Which answered the question and was efficient (assuming the implementation of std::string used copy on write (If the implementation was really good the erase could actually be done as part of the creation thus invoking no extra cost and a small string that had no erase would cost absolutely nothing). Don't understand why Charles deleted his answer (apart from Zenikoder silly remarks about score being a factor).

Comment: @Zenikoder: In practice that will work fine on any "normal" C++ library implementation, but you should be aware that there is no requirement that `c_str()` give you back an in-place representation of the string -- it is allowed to make a copy, in which case your several calls to it would make things slower.  (The motivation for this is that in theory the string library might not null-terminate its internal representation.  I'm 99% confident no library does this however as it would mean opening an memory management can of worms.)

Comment: @Martin: Charles's answer plainly didn't meet the requirements when overlapping strings were asked for.  His interpretation of the requirements was clearly wrong, since the same interpretation would have allowed for the original string to be passed back as-is.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: I agree about that rule regarding c_str, but in practise and reality, is there a faster way to implement c_str than how its being done today?

Comment: @ j_random_hacker: I disagree. The solution provided matched the problem stated above. The difference is in interpretation of the problem (which as any interview will tell you is part of the problem).

Comment: @Zenikoder: Rather than use c_str() you can use &s[0] as you are not relying on the null terminator.

Comment: @Martin: Which std::string implementations use COW? AFAIK, GNU, MS (Dinkum) and STLPort "DO NOT" use COW.

Comment: Why are you passing n by const ref? It's just a simply size_t. Pass it by value.

Comment: @Alex that is true, as for a 32-bit or 64-bit system the reference is just as large as the std::size_t type itself, so push the ref or the copy of original onto the stack is the same amount of effort - it shouldn't matter either way as no aliasing is occuring, furthermore I don't think there's anything wrong with a bit of const-correctness.

Comment: @Zenikoder: 1) You **CAN'T** say X does not support COW. You need to say **Version A of X** does not support COW. And yet the version of the STL that is provided with my very old GNU gcc compiler (3.4.4) does support it. Thus it will be soported by STLPort which is just a wrapper on the current implementation STL to correct for bugs and I don't care to check others since this quick test already showed your statement to be absolutely false.

Comment: @Martin: Sometimes there's no way to decide which of several interpretations is correct, but my point was that's not the case here: Charles's interpretation ("generate a subsequence of the given string that includes both the leading and trailing n characters") could not be the correct one here, because it would also be satisfied by simply passing back the original string as-is.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see how COW can be supported efficiently on any STL package that is intended to be used in multi-threaded environments. Hence I am sure that the STL that comes with my current version of gcc, vs9-10 does not support it, I'm not sure about c++ tool chains from about 10-15 years ago, but today that is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Zenikoder: I had to dig a bit, but sure enough 21.3/2 in the standard says that the `std::string` type's iterators are Random Access Iterators, meaning that you could replace expressions like `s.c_str() + n` (which *probably* will take O(1) time) with expressions like `s.begin() + n` (which *definitely* will take O(1) time) and use the version of `string::append()` that takes an iterator-pair instead.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Sorry, I made a mistake on the crucial word. I meant: "generate a subsequence of the given string that includes only both the leading and trailing n characters". Anyway, right or wrong it was obvious that my solution was not of interest.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Complexity measure and actual measurements are different, the std::string::iterator is very very slow on most if not all STLs when compared to the use of c_str or &s[0],  try timing a copy eg: std::copy(s.begin(),s.end,r.begin()) vs std::copy(&s[0], &s[0] + s.size(),&r[0]) there is a pretty big difference.

Comment: @Charles: OK, I'll grant you that it's definitely a question I would have asked the interviewer for clarification on, just to be sure.

Comment: @Zenikoder: I see...  Well, that's pretty tragic IMHO.  (You used full optimisation, right?)

Comment: @Zenikoder: Whether you understand it or not is really beside the point. It has temporarily been removed from compilers that support the new standard C++0x until people that are much smarter than you and I figure out how to do it properly. So yes on experimental compilers that are not currently being used in the real world (ie not be businesses yet (by the time it becomes commercially useful who knows what optimizations will have been put back)) it has been removed for safety.

Comment: @ j_random_hacker: <quote>could not be the correct one here, because it would also be satisfied by simply passing back the original string as-is</quote> Which in my interpretation (of the original question before the unit tests were added) was a well spotted optimization technique that as an interviewer I would have found interesting.

Comment: @Martin: I don't think gcc 4.4 or vs 9.0 or vs 10.0 to be "experimental" compilers - they don't support COW in their std::string implementation, supporting COW for std::string causes more inefficiencies and problems than it resolves, its been like that for a while now, memory is cheap yada yada.    btw Martin if you think there's an STL that does, could you please provide a version and possible a file/line number that i can have a quick look at, i've got access to most C++ compilers available (excluding hpux platform)

Comment: @Zenikoder: gcc 4.4.5 (a recent gcc) 3.4.4 (an older gcc) look in `bits/basic_string.tcc` They both seem to be doing copy on write.

Comment: It is interesting that your own solution doesn't pass the test (wrong interface).

Comment: @Martin are you talking about: _M_rep() in assign(const basic_string& __str) http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jwicks/libstdc++/html_user/basic__string_8tcc-source.html  -  if so i think you're confusing small strings and COW.

Comment: @UncleBens: The tests were something i added, after I discovered that some people are willing to hold onto their solution rather than accept a misunderstanding occured, obviously my interface wont pass, but its trivial to make it passable, but again, thats not at issue here, the issue is efficient processing and understanding all the little places C++ hides allocations etc behind the scenes.

Comment: I love TDD. `std::string first_last_n(int n, std::string s) { return "01234567890123456789"; }` passes both tests and should be quite fast ;-) .

Comment: @Charles: As they say, you can only test for what you know, and nothing else... :D

Comment: @Zenikoder: Relatively sure its not me that's confused (though it is always possible).

Comment: @Zenikoder: I am positive that GNU libstdc++ uses copy-on-write. Look inside `bits/basic_string.h` for `_M_refcount` (which has type `_Atomic_word`) and the call to `__exchange_and_add_dispatch`, etc.

Comment: Did you ask the interviewer what s/he thinks is the optimal way?

Comment: @Zenikoder: <quote>Complexity measure and actual measurements are different, the std::string::iterator is very very slow on most if not all STLs</quote> Seriously! If the compiler does not compile that down to a pointer I would be very disappointed at the compilers optimizer. On gcc the wrapper is so thin that its never going to be anything but a pointer (after optimization).

Comment: More than the various optimizations discussed in the comments and answers, personally, I'm more interested to know what the interviewer thought. Was there more discussion about what he thought would be better? Were trade-offs discussed? The fact that something 'optimized' for one compiler implementation might have a different optimization on another?  etc.

Comment: @Daniel: I did ask, he said there was definetly a better way, but that he wasn't going to say/how etc.

Comment: I am *so* glad I have never had to be interviewed like that, and suffer through such a stupid question.

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey: Such questions aren't really aimed for "grumpy old socks" like yourself... :D

Comment: `r.resize(0);` ? What's wrong with `clear` ?

Answer (score 6):

This implementation should be fast:

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
    n = std::min(n, s.size());
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(2*n);
    ret.append(s.begin(), s.begin() + n);
    ret.append(s.end() - n, s.end());
    return ret;
}
```

It [passes all three unit tests](http://codepad.org/ZaXR11u9).

When using GNU libstdc++, the line that declares & initializes `ret` is extremely fast because libstdc++ uses a global "empty string" variable. Thus, it's simply a pointer copy. Calls to `begin` and `end` on `s` are also fast because they will resolve to the const versions of `begin` and `end`, `begin() const` and `end() const`, so the internal representation of `s` is not "leaked". With libstdc++, `std::string::const_iterator` is `const char*`, which is a pointer type and random access iterator. Thus, when `std::string::append<const char*>(const char*, const char*)` calls [`std::distance`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/distance/) to obtain the length of the input range, it is a pointer difference operation. Also, `std::string::append<const char*>(const char*, const char*)` results in something like a `memmove`. Finally, the `reserve` operation ensures that enough memory is available for the return value.

**EDIT:**
For the curious, here is the initialization of `ret` in the assembly output of MinGW g++ 4.5.0:

```
    movl    $__ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE+12, (%ebx)
```

It's simply copying the pointer to the global "empty representation".

**EDIT2:**
Okay. I have now tested four variants with g++ 4.5.0 and Visual C++ 16.00.30319.01:

Variant 1 (the "c_str variant"):

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
   std::string::size_type s_size = s.size();
   n = std::min(n, s_size);
   std::string ret;
   ret.reserve(2*n);
   const char *s_cStr = s.c_str(), *s_cStr_end = s_cStr + s_size;
   ret.append(s_cStr, s_cStr + n);
   ret.append(s_cStr_end - n, s_cStr_end);
   return ret;
}
```

Variant 2 (the "data string" variant):

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
   std::string::size_type s_size = s.size();
   n = std::min(n, s_size);
   std::string ret;
   ret.reserve(2*n);
   const char *s_data = s.data(), *s_data_end = s_data + s_size;
   ret.append(s_data, s_data + n);
   ret.append(s_data_end - n, s_data_end);
   return ret;
}
```

Variant 3:

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
   std::string::size_type s_size = s.size();
   n = std::min(n, s_size);
   std::string ret(s);
   std::string::size_type d = s_size - n;
   return ret.replace(n, d, s, d, n);
}
```

Variant 4 (my original code):

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
   n = std::min(n, s.size());
   std::string ret;
   ret.reserve(2*n);
   ret.append(s.begin(), s.begin() + n);
   ret.append(s.end() - n, s.end());
   return ret;
}
```

The results for g++ 4.5.0 are:

- Variant 4 is the fastest
- Variant 3 is second (5% slower than variant 4)
- Variant 1 is third (2% slower than variant 3)
- Variant 2 is fourth (0.2% slower than variant 1)

The results for VC++ 16.00.30319.01 are:

- Variant 1 is the fastest
- Variant 2 is second (3% slower than variant 1)
- Variant 4 is third (4% slower than variant 2)
- Variant 3 is fourth (17% slower than variant 4)

Unsurprisingly, the variant that is fastest depends on the compiler. However, not knowing which compiler will be used I think that my variant is best because it is a familiar style of C++, it is the fastest when using g++, and it is not that much slower than variants 1 or 2 when using VC++.

One thing interesting from the VC++ results is that using `c_str` rather than `data` is faster. Perhaps that is why your interviewer said that there is a faster way than your implementation.

**EDIT3:**

Actually, I just thought about another variant:

Variant 5:

```
inline std::string first_last_n(std::string::size_type n, const std::string& s)
{
   n = std::min(n, s.size());
   std::string ret;
   ret.reserve(2*n);
   std::string::const_iterator s_begin = s.begin(), s_end = s.end();
   ret.append(s_begin, s_begin + n);
   ret.append(s_end - n, s_end);
   return ret;
}
```

It's just like variant 4 except that the begin and end iterators for `s` are saved.

When variant 5 is tested, it actually beats out variant 2 (the data string variant) when using VC++:

- Variant 1 is the fastest
- Variant 5 is second (1.6% slower than variant 1)
- Variant 2 is third (1.4% slower than variant 5)
- Variant 4 is third (4% slower than variant 2)
- Variant 3 is fourth (17% slower than variant 4)

Comment: Also note that NRVO may be done by the compiler, thus removing the cost of copying the value back.

Comment: Your comment about std::string::const_iterator may be true for gnu stl, but its certainly not the case for msvc stl. I believe a solution should take into account a few of the more widely used STLs and their implementation idiosyncrasies, not just one.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be just a pointer even with gnu (perhaps such an implementation is possible, but it would be considered very bad taste because of the hidden errors this can create). However, after optimizations I'd expect the binary to be an exact equivalent. - If you consider msvc's stl and performance, then either you don't use it at all, or you disable all the debugging code it contains?

Comment: @visitor: I don't understand what you wrote. Is there another way to phrase what you mean?

Comment: @Daniel + @Zenikoder: Even if it's not a `const char *`, it must be a random access iterator, which implies that the `std::distance` call used in `append` will always be efficient. (In MSVC it usually results in a check to ensure the two iterators are from the same container, but that's about it)

Comment: @Zenikoder: I have updated my answer with results for Visual C++. One thing that I found interesting is that using `c_str` rather than `data` is faster. Perhaps that is why your interviewer said that there is a faster implementation than the one you wrote during the interview.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: I've tried your variant 1 option on vs2010, gcc44, intel v11 and clang 2.8 and on all cases used PGO, your routine is still much slower than mine.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: I'm not sure what string implementation you are using, but for const access to a string, using data() is much faster than c_str. in fact they should be exactly the same for c++0x implementations as the small string optimization has been scrapped.

Comment: @Zenikoder: I didn't test your routine. I only tested the variants above—exactly as listed. As for `data` vs. `c_str`, I checked again (because it is surprising) and with both g++ and VC++ with or without C++0x enabled, `c_str` was slightly faster than `data` (variant 1 was slightly faster than variant 2) using my benchmark program.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to maintain the contents of the original string, then you can copy the last n characters into positions `[n+1, 2n]` of the original string and truncate it at `2n`. You will have to be careful to first expand the string and also be careful not to overwrite any characters before writing to them if the string is shorter than `2n`.

This will halve the number of operations to construct the string, as well as remove the need to create a new string. So its theoretically between 2 and 4 times faster. But of course you have just destroyed the original string, which you'd have to ask the interviewer if it is acceptable.

Comment: The original input string is used subsequently, so mutating/chaning it is now allowed.

Comment: @Zenikoder: The string is (well was) passed by value, so there's no problem manipulating the copy in place in the function body and returning it.

Comment: @Charles It was passed as a const reference, which cannot be modified by the function.

Comment: @Charles Passing by value and then doing what I suggested here is less efficient than passing by reference and then doing what @Zenikoder did.

Answer (score 1):

How about removing the middle N-2n characters, where N is the length of the source string?

Comment: Proposing an idea is great, but how this particular one you have going to incur less copies/shuffles and instantiations than the examples already provided by others and myself? - in short a code example will be better able to provide us with your insights.

Answer (score 1):

```
// compiled with cl /Ox first_last_n.cpp /W4 /EHsc

inline void
first_last_n2(string::size_type n, const std::string &s, string &out)  // method 2
{
  // check against degenerate input
  assert(n > 0);
  assert(n <= s.size());

  out.reserve(2*n);
  out.assign(s, 0, n);
  out.append(s, s.size()-n, n);
}
```

Times:

```
method 1:  // original method
2.281
method 2:  // my method
0.687
method 3:  // your code.
0.782
```

Note: Timing specifically tests "long" strings. I.e. those where short string optimization is not used. (My strings were 100 length).

Comment: Are asserts generated in release mode? If they're not then your timings are off.

Comment: @Zenikoder: They are generated as long as NDEBUG is not defined. I tested both with and without -- made almost no difference.

Answer (score 0):

My only thought is that if this function is only called with C null-terminated strings, you might be requiring the extra construction of a std::string for parameter 's'.

Possibly the 'more' efficient method would be to allow either a std::string or const char *s passed in.

Comment: You really can't make an assumption like that when working with the std::string type.

Comment: @Zenikoder can't assume that a copy isn't made?  I don't know if the standard requires it but I haven't seen an implementation of std::string::string( const char * ) constructor which doesn't copy the string.

Answer (score 0):

Memcpy is a cheat?

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string first_last_n(int n, const std::string& s)
{
  if (s.size() < n)
      return "";

    char str[n*2];
    memcpy(str, s.data(), n);
    memcpy(str+n, s.data() + s.size()-n, n);

    return (const char *)str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << first_last_n(2, "123454321") << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT**
So I removed the other one. This is not a cheat.

Comment: initially using anything from the standard libraries isn't a cheat, so memcpy is fine, however why go to all the trouble of fiddling with memory on the stack only to have to copy all back into a string instance, why not do all the fiddling with the actual result string?

Comment: Return value optimization will happen here, so there is no need for a refernce for a result object.

Comment: Can you guarantee RVO will take place? its not a mandated behavior in the C++ standard, and most optimizers are very selective in how/when they do it.

Comment: Yes. There was a debate with collegues two or three mounth ago in the same question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: But in this case maybe not will happen because the original and the return type is not the same. Hmm..

Comment: Variable-length arrays are a feature of C99 that I do not think is available in standard C++. Also, `str` is not null-terminated.

Comment: This code relies on non-standard variable-length arrays, though.

Comment: Google said that "C++ extends Standard C++ and C++98 to support variable length arrays for compatibility with C99." http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc03variable_length_arrays.htm maybe it is not true

Comment: Isn't there a slight bug with this only copying 9 out of the 10 last characters? Your array needs to be 2*n+1.  2*n for the characters and one for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

If you must pass the tests then you're going to have to write inefficient code, because you must return a copy of a string. This implies you must use dynamic allocation, possibly multiple times because of the copy.

So change the tests and change the signature.

```
template<class Out>
Out first_last_n(const std::string::size_type& n, const std::string& s, Out r)
{
    r = copy_n(s.begin(), n, r);
    std::string::const_iterator pos(s.end());
    std::advance(pos, -n);
    return copy_n(pos, n, r);
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
std::string s("Hello world!");
char r[5];
r[4] = 0;
first_last_n(2, s, r);
```

This allows you to use dynamic programming, and it eliminates the need of dynamic allocation in the function.

I like my algorithms minimalistic, and I purposely eliminated the check for `n` being smaller or equal to the size of the string. I replace the check with a pre-condition for the function. Preconditions are faster than checks: they have zero overhead.

Comment: As has been noted, its the value in r at the end of the day that is important. feel free to modify the tests as long as the actual values remain the same.