# std::string copy constructor NOT deep in GCC 4.1.2?

Tags: c++, gcc, copy-constructor, deep-copy, stdstring

I wonder if i misunderstood something: does a copy constructor from `std::string` **not** copy its content?

```
string str1 = "Hello World";
string str2(str1);

if(str1.c_str() == str2.c_str()) // Same pointers!
  printf ("You will get into the IPC hell very soon!!");
```

This will print "You will get into the IPC hell very soon!!" and it annoys me.

Is this the normal behavior of `std::string`? I read somewhere that it usually does a deep copy.

However, this works as expected:

```
string str3(str1.c_str());

if(str1.c_str() == str3.c_str()) // Different pointers!
  printf ("You will get into the IPC hell very soon!!");
else
  printf ("You are safe! This time!");
```

It copies the contents into the new string.

Comment: Try modifying `str2` in your first example (e.g. `str2[0] = 'B';`) and *then* comparing the `c_str()` values.

Comment: For what it's worth, GCC 4.7 has the same behaviour both in C++03 and C++11 modes (and @Angew's suggestion indeed yields different `c_str()` values).

Comment: Appearently it allocates a new buffer after the edit u sugested @Angew . So it seems to be some sort of "optimization" ... it costed us several hour of work to find that problem.*sigh*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is entirely possible that your `string` implementation uses copy-on-write which would explain the behavior. Although this is less likely with newer implementations (and non-conforming on C++11 implementations).

The standard places no restriction on the value of the pointer returned by `c_str` (besides that it points to a null-terminated c-string), so your code is inherently non-portable.

Comment: Why is COW less likely with newer implementations.

Comment: @user93353 COW is not possible to implement if you want to be C++11 conforming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11

Comment: @user93353: COW can severily decrease performance in multithreaded environments. For that reason it has lost a lot of popularity (and been banned in C++11).

Comment: @user93353 Lots of people disagree with respect to multi-threading. There are also move semantics, which handle a lot of classic cases where COW used to be helpful.

Comment: Yepp it like you said. Good to know NOW ... Thanks! I will accept your answer later, i ll just wait if somebody else has an something interesting to say about this.

Comment: As I said in another comment, GCC 4.7 in C++11 mode has the same behaviour. Looking at the sources `/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h` it is indeed COW (meh what about C++11 conformance?...).

Comment: @syam This is considered a defect and might change: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-c11 and the linked thread.

Answer (score 5):

`std::string` implementation in your compiler must be reference counted. Change one of the strings and then check the pointers again - they would be different.

```
string str1 = "Hello World";
string str2(str1);

if(str1.c_str() == str2.c_str()) // Same pointers!
  printf ("You will get into the IPC hell very soon!!");

str2.replace(' ',',');

// Check again here.
```

These are 3 excellent articles on reference counted strings.

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/043.htm

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/044.htm

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/045.htm

Comment: I did, as i pointed out in my comment on the question itself and its like said above: it does a copy on write!