# Will std::string.assign(const char*) or op= ( with const char *) create a copy of the char*?

Tags: c++, string

Digging through the c++ code, it looks like it does a copy, but I cannot be sure.  By "copy", I mean something like strcpy is happening internally.  And std:string doesn't end up with a pointer to the same char* internally it was passed.

```
const char *somestring = ...
std::string str;
str.assign(somestring);
// or
str = somestring;  //in my impl, op= calls to assign(const char*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` will always copy from the array pointed to by a `char *`. You can also provide an iterator range in some constructors.

Copy or reference counting during copies of one `std::string` to another depends on the C++ library that you are using.

The C++ 2011 standard requires std::string to make real copies. The 2003 standard allowed reference counted copies.

The GNU libstdc++ uses reference counted strings. And for backward compatibility, even the 2011 standard GCC builds with them. Otherwise it couldn't link to code built with the 2003 standard.

There is a preprocessor definition to turn on the new behavior.

See also [std::string copy constructor NOT deep in GCC 4.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604925/stdstring-copy-constructor-not-deep-in-gcc-4-1-2) and [Is std::string refcounted in GCC 4.x / C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-c11)

Comment: Reference counting can happen when copying strings. But this question is about copying a `const char *`, which cannot be reference counted.

Comment: @interjay: Also mentions operator= though.

Comment: It mentions `operator=` with a `const char*` parameter.

Comment: @interjay: I can see how you read it that way, although I didn't.

Comment: @interjay yes, operator= w/ const char* is what I meant.  Sorry for confusion.

Comment: good to know about string to string copy behavior, too.  Thanks.