# char initialization constructor in c++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have write this constructor to initialize the character type array

```
class StudentInfo
{
  char* vuId;
public:
  StudentInfo(char* vu_Id)
  {
    setVuId(vu_Id);
  }
  void setVuId(char* vu_Id)
  {
    vuId = new char[strlen(vu_Id) + 1];
    strcpy(vuId, vu_Id);
  }
};
```

This code is working fine. but I want to initialize without having to call setVuId function. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Move `setVuId`'s body into constructor? Also suggest use `std::string` instead.

Comment: Can I question your desire to avoid calling setVuId in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

sure:

```
#include <string>

class StudentInfo
{
  std::string vuId;
public:
  explicit StudentInfo(const char* vu_Id) : vuId(vu_Id) {}
```

};

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of last line ? I know its  a constructor with a pointer to const charcter parameter but what is " : vuId(vu_Id)"

Comment: @Vivek: it passes the argument to the constructor of std::string when member vuID is constructed. google for 'c++ contsructor initialization list' for more details

Comment: Hey Pal - make the constructor explicit, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string if you can tolerate copy-on-write and associated overhead, else use this:

```
#include <cstring>

class StudentInfo
{
  size_t len;
  char* data;

public:
  StudentInfo(char* vu_Id):
    len(vu_Id ? strlen(vu_Id) : 0),
    data(len ? (char*)memcpy(new char[len + 1], vu_Id, len + 1) : 0)
  {
  }

  virtual ~StudentInfo() {
    delete [] data;
  }
}
```

Comment: IIRC C++11 does not allow COW for ``std::string``.

Comment: yes, on the paper, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-c11

Comment: replace strncpy with memcpy and take care of Rule of 3

Comment: gcc does COW, MSVC the small string optimisation