# C++ Memory Management: RAII, Smart Pointers and GC

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection, smart-pointers

Here are my thoughts of C++ Memeory management, please feel free to comment.

Memory can be allocated in **stack** or **heap**.

**Rule 1:**

If two **nested stacks** need to share data, use RAII allocating memory in **stack**, like below:

```
func1() {
    Resource res;  // res will be destructed once func1 returns
    func2( &res );
}
```

**Rule 2:**

If two **parallel stacks** need to share data (not class member fields), memory must be allocated in **heap**, use Smart Points or GC. For example:

```
func() {
    shared_ptr<Resource> res = func1();   // returned a shared ptr to a memory allocated in func1
    func2( res );
}
```

Am I correct?

Comment: What is your question exactly? And with respect to what, the standard? Because strictly speaking C++ has no concept of a "stack" or "heap", at least not when discussing the memory model.

Comment: RAII, shared_pointer are used when polymorphism is involved

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that you are right, (**parallel stacks** means multithread I suppose)

Also is ok to use `scoped_ptr`(boost) or `unique_ptr`(c++11) in your first case. In that case object is allocate in memory `heap` instead of `stack`. and RAII also free that memory after the scope is finished.

shared_ptr is a reference count mechanism, so if other object keep the `shared_ptr`(in your case:`func2`), and didn't release it after your `func` scope finished, the object `shared_ptr` is still available.

Comment: The example for case 2 is single-threaded, so I think you're reading too much into this.

Comment: @MSalters I don't really understand the parallel stacks, because single thread could only have one stack at a time.

Comment: Gohan, yes a single thread only have one stack. Here, I treat a function as one stack.

Comment: I now understand you more, in your case 2, `func1` allocate a object, and return. `Resource res = func1()` when `Resource` is a big object not a Resource handle, this approach is consider not effective, better to use scoped_ptr/shared_ptr to do so. (c++ 11 has a move assign operator, I think it could help you to use `Resource res = func1()` like approach, having equally performance like xxx_ptr approach)

Answer (score 0):

No. Your example 2 is better written as just

```
void func() {
    Resource res = func1();   // func1 returns a Resource
    func2( res ); // func2 uses that Resource.
}
```

Comment: I disagree with you. The 'res' is destroyed once it leaves func1(), so must return a raw pointer (manually delete after func2()) or a smart_pointer. If you mean 'res' holds a pointer to a block of memory inside, then 'res' itself is a smart pointer.

Comment: @Zach: Wrong. `res` doesn't even _exist_ in `func1` so it can't be destroyed. But just try it with `std::string` as a resource: From `func1`, return `std::string("Hi")`, and see that the code above will pass Hi to `func2`.

Comment: std::string is ref counted. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-4-x-c11

Comment: @Zach: Note that the linked question talks specifically about GCC, **and** notes that the GCC implementation is in fact wrong. Even so, that would not change anything. `std::string` is not a smart pointer, as it lacks both `operator*` and `operator->`.

Comment: MSalters: in your code, func1() returns Resource, can you show the inside code of func1()? how does it allocate memory?

Comment: @Zach: Taking `std::string` as an example, like this: `std::string func1() { return "hi"; }`. As you can see, no mention of `res` nor a mention of `new`. Using RAII, the resource class (`std::string`) manages memory. See `std::allocator` for all the details

Comment: MSalters: 'std::string' may be a little special, because "hi" may not be allocated in stack. Can you use a class of your own?

Comment: @Zach: I've got no idea what you mean with that "not on stack" argument. But exactly the same principle applies to `std::map<int, float>` for instance, or `std::complex<double>`. Many, many classes in C++ have value behavior.

Comment: in `std::string func1() { return "hi"; }. `  , do you mean the two chars in the string are copied when return? What if it is a very long string, are all chars in the string be copied too?

Comment: Well, the string _literal_ is a constant, and the `std::string` is modifiable, so you by necessity have that one copy - but that's a detail of the example initialization. After that, the string is _moved_ out, not copied.