# Can std::shared_ptr<std::string const> serve as an efficient implementation of reference-counted immutable strings?

Tags: c++, string, immutability, std

Ideally, an immutable string class would only need one memory allocation for each string. Even the reference count could be stored in the same chunk of memory that holds the string itself.

A trivial implementation of `string` and `shared_ptr` would allocate three distinct pieces of memory for `shared_ptr<string const>`:

- Memory for the string buffer
- Memory for the string object
- Memory for the reference count

Now, I know that when using `std::make_shared()`, it is possible for a smart implementation to combine the last two into a single allocation. But that would still leave two allocations.

When you know that the string is immutable, the string buffer won't be reallocated, hence it should be possible to integrate it with the string object, leaving only one allocation.

I know that some string implementations already use such optimizations for short strings, but I'm after an implementation that does this regardless of string length.

My questions are: Is my reasoning sound? Is an implementation actually permitted and able to do this? Can I reasonably expect from a good quality standard library to implement this optimization? Do you know of contemporary library implementations which do this?

Or is this something I would have to implement myself?

Comment: GCC 4.x had reference counted `std::string`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520192/is-stdstring-refcounted-in-gcc-4-x-c11 .  Later versions of GCC still have it if you compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Comment: have a look at [allocate_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared)

Comment: @Caleth That won't help, it works much like `make_shared` except it uses an explicit allocator.

Comment: There is a reference-counted immutable string in the standard library. It's spelled `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: @T.C. That made me almost LOL... :) But the string is still *separatley allocated*. So still two allocations: One for the object and one for the string.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to send a proposal for the C++ standards committee about a `std::immutable_shared_ptr` class with a `std::make_immutable_shared_ptr` function that can allocate all data as a single block of memory? And make a Boost implementation as a proof-of-concept?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I *think* that my custom allocator below is roughly correct

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, `runtime_error` handles the reference counting for you, so it stands in for the `shared_ptr` :)

Comment: @T.C. Semantically immutable objects can support built-in reference counting, via a hidden `mutable` member, whose existence is not exposed to applications.

Comment: @Kaz What does that have to do with anything I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the only way to do this is a `make_shared` which accepts arrays of run-time variable size. The standard one [does not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared#Notes), even as of c++17 (which adds support for `shared_ptr` to arrays).

Boost, on the other hand, has [`boost::make_shared`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared_array.html), which can take an array size parameter as well. Once you have that, you're golden; you get a `shared_ptr<char[]>` which does pretty much what you want (besides actually being a `std::string`.

If you don't want to use boost you could just roll your own. It probably wouldn't be that hard.

Something else to consider is that if you will only ever create O(1) strings, it will be much faster to just never delete them, and pass around raw pointers (or `std::string_view`s) instead. This avoids any copying, or fiddling with reference counts. (The reference counts are actually quite slow, since they use atomic operations.)

You could also use an interning mechanism like `std::unordered_set<std::string>`.

Comment: If using C++17, you could wrap your `boost::shared_ptr<char[]>` in a simple class which gets you easy access to a `std::string_view`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Not having the interface of a std::string is a definite drawback, however. I thought about using std::string_view, but how do I actually get at the size of the array?

Comment: @sh- Hm, it looks like you actually can't. I guess you would have to use null-terminated strings if you did it this way.

Comment: Or store the length manually in the first few bytes of the string. At that point I might as well implement the entire thing myself.

Comment: @Dan: I do want to eventually delete the strings, once they're not used anymore. They are typically not short (often around 1k chars) and it isn't easy to devise a single owner. However, they do not change, once constructed. So shared ownership is the first thing that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably need to use a custom allocator for all of the allocation.

```
class ImmutableStringAllocator;

template<typename CharT>
using immutable_string = std::basic_string<CharT, std::char_traits<CharT>, ImmutableStringAllocator>

template<size_t N>
immutable_string<char> make_immutable_string(char (&data)[N])
{
    ImmutableStringAllocator alloc(N);
    // going for basic_string::basic_string(charT *, size_t, Allocator)
    return allocate_shared<immutable_string<char>>(alloc, data, N, alloc);
}

class ImmutableStringAllocator {
    size_t len;
    size_t offset;
    char * buf;
    std::reference_wrapper<char *> ref;
public:
    // Normal Allocator stuff here
    ImmutableStringAllocator(size_t N) : len(N), buf(nullptr), offset(0), ref(buf) {}

    ImmutableStringAllocator(const ImmutableStringAllocator & other) : len(other.len), buf(nullptr), offset(other.offset), ref(other.buf) {}

    ImmutableStringAllocator operator=(const ImmutableStringAllocator & other) 
    { 
         assert(buf == nullptr); 
         temp(other); 
         swap(*this, temp); 
         return *this; 
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n, const_void_pointer hint)
    {
         if (!ref.get()) { buf = ::new(n + len); offset = n; return buf; }
         return ref.get() + offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the allocator used by the shared_ptr to allocate the string object different than the one used by the string to allocate its storage?

Comment: According to cppreference, `allocate_shared` uses a copy of the allocator.